# Undefined array key "name"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

i wanted to add a subtotal to my cart page and i had this problem from laravel-9x, and actually i was watching a video on youtube that they used the same methode and that worked nicely with laravel 5.6
and i'm using this laravelshopping cart from github:
https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart

### **so this is my function :**

```
use Cart;
use App\Models\Produit;
use Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    //add product to card
    public function add(Request $request)
    {
        $produit = Produit::find($request->id);
        Cart::add(array(
            'id' => $produit->id, 
            'name' => $produit->nom,
            'price' => $produit->prix_ht,
            'quantity' => $request->qty,
            'attributes' => array('size'=>$request->size,
                                  'photo'=>$produit->photo_principale,
                                  'prix_ttc'=>$produit->prixTTC()
            )
        ));
        return redirect(route(name:'cart_index'));
        
    }
```

**and this is the function prixTTC():**

```
   public function prixTTC(){
        $prix_ttc = $this->prix_ht * self::$facteur_tva;
        return number_format($prix_ttc,2);
    }
```

### **and this is my HTML:**

```
                   <td>
                    {{ $produit->attributes['prix_ttc'] }} €
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        {{ number_format($produit->attributes['prix_ttc'] * $produit->quantity,2)}} €
                    </td>
```

and laravel gives me this message:
***Undefined array key "prix_ttc"***

Comment: please provide source code of the function "prixTTC()"

Comment: can you do `dd($produit)` and add output to question?

Comment: @RobBiermann because he adds the $produit to his $Cart with 'attributes':[...'prix_ttc'...]. 

For further analysis the source code of your classes Cart and Produit are relevant too.

Comment: `$produit` is a collection of your `Produit` model result. It don't even have attributes key. How you are trying to access it. If you have a relation between them first you have to call relation then access the attribute.

Comment: @geertjanknapen it's undefined variable!

Comment: @JohannesGriebenow i did it

Comment: @kr.Nada function looks fine. Please consider the comment from _Vüsal Hüseynli_, since this is likely to solve your problem.

Comment: @JohannesGriebenow i don't kniw how to do it, im beginner in  php

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli how can i do it

Comment: Please briefly explain what you are trying to do so we can help you. Is there a relation between them? Why are you holding array in attributes column. You can add another table for it and then relate them each other. If you don't know what I am talking about. Please read about database relations in laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: i'm following this laravelshoppingcart from github:https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart#usage

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score 0):

in "add" function

```
return redirect(route(name:'cart_index'))->with(['produit'=>$produit]);
```

I'm from morocco too

i hope it was useful .